# Which command to get vagrantfile changes on an instance

Tags: vagrant

I made changes to my Vagrantfile (added `config.vm.share_folder`, `config.vm.customize` lines) and now I want them to show up on the box. Do I need to run

```
vagrant destroy && vagrant up
```

Or is it sufficient to run

```
vagrant reload
```

? I am unclear about whether vagrant reload will read anything from the Vagrantfile, since it seems to shutdown the VM and run the provisioner.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think you need to destroy your VM.  You can make changes to VM configuration when the VM is not running and powered down.

Try using `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up`.

It should make the modifications to the VM as specified in Vagrantfile.

and you could also do `vagrant up --no-provision` to avoid re-provisioning as you bring up the VM.

and `vagrant reload [vm-name] --no-provision` should do the same trick.

Answer (score 7):

`vagrant reload` is same as running `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up` please refer the [doc for reload](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/reload.html). Here is an excerpt from the doc

"This command is usually required for changes made in the Vagrantfile to take effect. After making any modifications to the Vagrantfile, a reload should be called." So in your case, I would suggest you to only use,

```
vagrant reload
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```